# Custom User Login Template Error

Tags: 7, theming

I am using Drupal 7 and I have added some code to my template.php file in my theme (which I found on a Drupal tutorial) so I can use a custom template for the user login form. The form works and it is using the custom template but it is generating these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: classes_array in template_process() (line 2527 of /includes/theme.inc).
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in template_process() (line 2527 of /includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: attributes_array in template_process() (line 2533 of /includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: title_attributes_array in template_process() (line 2534 of /includes/theme.inc).
Notice: Undefined index: content_attributes_array in template_process() (line 2535 of /includes/theme.inc).
```

The code I have in my template.php file is:

```
function cr_theme() {
  $items = array();

  $items['user_login'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'cr') . '/templates',
    'template' => 'user-login',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
       'cr_preprocess_user_login'
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}

function cr_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
  $vars['forgot_link'] = l(t('Forgot password?'),'user/password');
}
```

and my user-login.tpl.php file contains:

```
<div class="cr-user-login-form-wrapper">
  <?php print drupal_render_children($form) ?>
<p style="margin-top:12px;"><?php print render($forgot_link); ?></p>
</div>
```

I have been trying to find the cause of the errors which I think is probably something I have not added to my cr_theme() function but now need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By playing around with the preprocess function I seem to have fixed the errors. I changed the preprocess function to:

```
function cr_preprocess_user_login(&$vars) {
  $vars['content_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'content';
  $vars['title_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'content';
  $vars['attributes_array']['class'][] = 'content';
  $vars['classes_array'] = array('content');
  $vars['forgot_link'] = l(t('Forgot password?'),'user/password');
}
```

I just added in the undefined indexes that were coming up in the errors. I'm really not completely sure what I am doing but it does seem to be removing the errors so far.

It would be great if someone could comment how this is working.

Answer (score 0):

I would try add back in all the default preprocess functions to the array, given that the system is whining about getting undefined indexes.

> preprocess functions: A list of functions used to preprocess this
>   data. Ordinarily this won't be used; it's automatically filled in. By
>   default, for a module this will be filled in as
>   template_preprocess_HOOK. For a theme this will be filled in as
>   phptemplate_preprocess and phptemplate_preprocess_HOOK as well as
>   themename_preprocess and themename_preprocess_HOOK.

Comment: Thank you cchen for taking the time to answer my query. I seem to have fixed it using the answer I have given, though I'm not completely sure how I managed it.

Comment: You're welcome @Ben glad you figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue (guessing I found & used the same tutorial referenced in the question... :)

Based on the info provided by cchen, I simply removed the preprocess array info:

```
   'preprocess functions' => array(
   'cr_preprocess_user_login'
),
```

Cleared cache, and that was it.

Also like you, I don't know enough about this stuff to understand why this worked.  All I can do is confirm it did.